# PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 322981888) (tried to allocate 67108872 bytes)

Tags: php

I am getting this error while I am taking input more than 20 as input
Here is my scripts. upto 20 as input value I can run in my local by using set_time_limit(0);ini_set("memory_limit","2000M"); or more but it doesn't care in hackerrank platform. I need to fix it in hackerrank with php
Input may be upto 65

```
<?php
 function generateInputCode($nbit) {

   $nlist = array();
   if($nbit == 2) {
     $nlist = array('00', '01', '11', '10'); 
     showResult($nlist,$nbit); 
   }
   elseif($nbit == 3) {
     $nlist = array('000', '001', '011', '010', '110', '111', '101', '100');
     showResult($nlist,$nbit); 

 }
   else{

         $listn = array('000', '001', '011', '010', '110', '111', '101', '100');
         for($bit = 4; $bit <= $nbit; $bit++){

                $l = count($listn);
                $reflectedlistn = array_reverse($listn);
                $lista = array();
                $listb = array();


                 array_walk($listn, function(&$value, $key) { $value = '0'.$value; });
                 $lista  = $listn;

                 array_walk($reflectedlistn, function(&$value, $key) { $value = '1'.$value; });
                 $listb  = $reflectedlistn; 

                $listn = array_merge($lista,$listb);

            }

        showResult($listn,$nbit); 

   } 

} 

function showResult($listm,$nbit){

    $ln = count($listm);
    for($i=$ln-$nbit;$i<$ln;$i++){
      print $listm[$i]."\n"; 
    }

}


$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$nbit = (int) fgets($handle);

if($nbit == 1) print 1;
elseif($nbit>1&&$nbit<=65) generateInputCode($nbit);

?>
```

Can anybody suggest?